# Accessing OAuth 2.0 APIs from Mule/CloudHub

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, mule, cloudhub

Tutorials/examples for accessing OAuth 2.0 based APIs with Mule seem to refer to either using connectors for specific services (Salesforce, Google), or creating custom connectors. How would one integrate to an API with just a regular HTTPS connector/endpoint when no custom connector is available? Do I need to manually configure all the whole handshake flows, storing and refreshing tokens, etc? I'm using the CloudHub version of Mule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create all this infrastructure by hand. Instead use DevKit to create a simple wrapper connector around the OAuth2-secured API you want to use.

You will receive OAuth2 support OOTB: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Implementing+OAuth+2.0+Authentication

Plus you will get a custom element you can use in Studio.